# Wordpress Upload function after server change

Tags: database, wordpress, upload, phpmyadmin

After a server change I get this error:
An error occurred in the upload. Please try again later

I checked the memory limit, the webspace, the wp-content directory and set the files to 777.

Nothing. After the server change I got some problems with the comment function.
A auto incremen problem in the database!

Maybe the same cause? Any ideas?

Greetings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, did you check the auto increment for wp_posts en wp_postmeta as well? The WordPress media library inserts posts in these tables, a failure to do so will result in a error.